# use regex to copy artifacts from another project

Tags: regex, jenkins, continuous-integration

Is it possible to use regex to filter "artifacts to copy" when copy artifacts from another project?

I know it is possible to use "*" or "**", but is it possible to do more than that? 
e.g., if I have the following artifacts:
build.out
build_revision_2010.out

And i want to copy only "build_revision_2010.out" rather than "build.out". Is it possible to do it?

something like `(.*_){2}[0-9]{4}.out`

Comment: Substitute `.` with `\S`: `(\S+_){2}[0-9]{4}\.out`

Comment: @revo Agreed. https://regex101.com/r/Z4S9gV/1

Comment: [`\s\K(?:.*_){2}\d{4}\.out`](https://regex101.com/r/L6LYAH/1)